# Subtract and divide math using php oop

Tags: php, oop, math

I'm learning php oop now. I was trying to do something like this.

```
$firstnumber=100;
$secoendnumber=30;
$difference=$firstnumber-$secoendnumber;
$changePercent=($difference*100)/$secoendnumber;
```

For me if I write it in procedural it is very easy. But I can't figure out how to do the same using oop. So, I don't have to Subtract and divide again and again if require.

I was trying something like this for oop page

```
class subtract{
    var $number,$number1,$result;
    public function set_number($new_number,new_number1,result){
        $this->number=$new_number;
        $this->number=$new_number1;
        $this->result=$new_number-$new_number1;
    }
    public function get_number($new_number){
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

And for Index.php

```
$firstvalue=new subtract;
$nextvalue= new subtract;
$firstvalue->set_number($number);
$nextvalue->set_number($number1);
echo $change->get_number();
```

Comment: Have you started with some code?

Comment: Yes. But I guess I need to use array or something? That is mainly confusing me.

Comment: *Yes* Good! Then show us your attempt so we can see where you're stuck, where you need help, so we can explain to you what you did wrong or how to do it right/better

Comment: That's all i'm trying so far

Comment: So you are just trying to create a "calculator" class?

Comment: Yes that is all I'm trying to create.

Comment: You defined a function setNumber to take 3 parameters but then only send one in....

Comment: You can take inspiration from [this library](https://github.com/Herzult/SimplePHPEasyPlus) ;)

Comment: If you guys are not capable enough to answer a question properly then stop adding silly comments. It can save everyone's time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not answering my own question prove myself a nerd or genius. Just answering so someone like me can find the answer easily without banging his/her head against the wall.

Index.php will look like

```
$test=1000;
$testa=900;
$input=new changeValue;
$input->currentfigure=$test;
$input->previousfigure=$testa;
echo $input->get_value();
```

backend.php will look like

```
class changeValue{
    var $currentfigure;
    var $previousfigure;
    var $change;
    public function get_value (){

        return $this->change=$this->currentfigure-$this->previousfigure;

    }
```